# Создание *.mdb читабельного файла

Tags: access, delphi

Добрый вечер! Вопрос такой:

Как создать `mdb` базы (файла) из под Дельфи? Именно формата `mdb`, а не просто с таким расширением.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ключевое слово - `ADOX.Catalog`.  Оно приводит к многим интересным ссылкам.

- [Работа с ADO в Delphi. Часть 8. Библиотека ADOX](http://devdelphi.ru/?p=1251)
- [Borland Delphi и расширения ADO](http://www.olap.ru/desc/microsoft/borland_ado.asp)
- [прям рабочий вариант](http://forum.codeby.net/topic17723.html)

Comment: спасибо, неплохие ссылки